# AWS Load Balancer Presenting Old SSL Certificate After Replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I'm having an issue with load balancing and SSL. Currently I have a single load balancer with one single listener, and sitting behind that is for now just a single EC2 instance. During development I have been using a self-signed certificate, and that was working perfectly.

The problem is now that I've purchased a "real" certificate and replaced it in my single listener, I am still seeing the old self-signed certificate. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Configured the "SSL Certificate" of my listener by choosing "Upload a new SSL certificate". No errors were reported here.
2. Deleted the old certificate to verify it was not in use by running "*aws iam delete-server-certificate --server-certificate-name=OLD_SELF_SIGNED_CERT*". When I now run "*aws iam list-server-certificates*", I see only one certificate listed and it is the new certificate I purchased and uploaded in (1). I'm positive the new certificate is shown, as the "Expiration" field of the command output is a date in 2017 whereas the old self-signed certificate expired in 2016. As well, the "Certificate Name" dropdown in the "Select Certificate" window for the load balancer listener only lists the new certificate.
3. When I hit the load balancer in all web browsers I've tried (on Windows, Mac, and phone) I am presented with a warning regarding the certificate. Viewing the certificate shows it is the old self-signed certificate that was supposedly removed.
4. Running "*openssl s_client -showcerts -connect LOAD_BALANCER_URL*" also displays the old self-signed certificate.

So the AWS management interface and the AWS CLI tools are reporting that the new certificate is in use, but none of my web browsers on any machine nor openssl show the new certificate.

I have tried re-uploading the new certificate (and confirmed I did not inadvertently re-upload the old self-signed certificate), as well as deleting and re-creating the listener. I have not yet tried removing the load balancer entirely, as the documentation states what I'm trying to achieve should be possible. I thought as well maybe there's just a small delay, but according to the AWS documentation ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-update-ssl-cert.html ): "Note that replacing a certificate does not affect requests that were received by a load balancer node and are pending routing to a healthy instance, ***but the new certificate will be used with subsequent requests that are received***" (emphasis added). To me that sounds like it takes effect immediately. But as I've stated I have issued many requests over the course of about an hour here, and I'm still seeing the old self-signed certificate.

Is deleting and re-creating the load balancer entirely my only option here? I can do that as a last resort, but I'm hoping there's maybe just something I've overlooked.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would go with creating a new ELB. I have seen problems with configuration of ELBs in the past (but not with the concrete problem you mention here).

Comment: Is this ELB in the `sa-east-1` (São Paulo) region, by chance?

Comment: @ZeissS Thanks for the info! I held out hope for a few more hours after I posted, but the new certificate was never presented. I went ahead and wiped that ELB then created a new one with the new certificate, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, this particular ELB was in US West (Oregon).

Comment: Ah, okay. The sa-east-1 region had a period of a couple of hours today where one availability zone was experiencing connectivity issues for several services,  including ELB, around the time you originally posted the question.  Glad to see you got it straightened out -- I haven't seen ELB do that before.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Under different circumstances it could've been a much bigger problem. I'm lucky that my project is still early and doesn't have a userbase, so wiping the ELB wasn't a huge deal. But I did have to update a DNS CNAME record to point to the new ELB, which meant my service was effectively unavailable via the 'public' address for somewhere around 12 hours.